# Find OS generated port before using socket.connect() in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I would like to ask if there any way to to create a socket in Python, using:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

And then, extract the port which going to be generated by the OS, before using:

```
sock.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
```

i.e. my goal is to find the source port of the first SYN packet which will be sent to the server, as part of the 3-way handshake, before actually executing the 3-way handshake.

Note: I figured out that finding out the generated port is possible using:

```
generated_port = sock.getsockname()[1]
```

But, unfortunately, the value of `generated_port` is set just after using `sock.connect()`.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local port is only available after the socket is bound to a local IP and port. If not explicitly done by calling `bind` this will be implicitly done doing `connect`. Therefore to get the local port before calling `connect` one has to explicitly call `bind` before that:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',0))
print(s.getsockname()[1])  
s.connect((host,port))
```

Comment: Thanks :) your solution is exactly what I was searching for